# API versioning and Data schema / Business Logic change

Tags: api, rest, versioning

Just curious to find out how others have approached this issue where you have multiple versions of API and how do you manage data that is consumed by these different versions.

Easier to explain my current issue with an example:

1. /v1/member/123/signin --> Represents version 1 of member signin
2. Now we have new feature to develop where we need to modify the signin workflow  to do the following:

   - Run some new business logic and award lets say badges to this member for signin
   - Return response which contains additional data in the JSON response.

Very quickly people say to use version and make this new feature **/v2/member/123/sigin**  but right now I am not clear on how to manage the data between different version

Lets say we make this a /v2/member/123/sigin, we need to make following changes:
1. Add few fields to Member table
2. Update signin workflow to award badges if member meets the bussiness rules
3. Return additional member details plus any badges that member has earned.

Now my problem is that when building the JSON response for V1 client I need to make sure not to include the new fields that was added in the Member table or return any new types such as Badges as V1 wouldn't know what to do with that and most likely break as V1 is already live in production and can't handle anything it doesn't understand and we cannot update this app.

Few people suggested to version the data in the database.

Keen to hear what's the best practice out there for such scenario and others doing as this is a common issue in versioning  ?